How can I reference methods defined in my main Flask File when I start dividing things into Blueprints?
So I started with
mainfolder/
    main.py <--- the entire flask app was in there but it got unruly so I though abou dividing things up in to blueprints...

the new way I was doing it is"
mainfolder/
    main.py <--- the entire flask app was in there but it got unruly so I though abou dividing things up in to blueprints
    blueprints/
      __init__.py

      blueprint1/
         __init__.py
         blueprint1.py

I have a method in my main.py called checkIt(){} ... however I have no idea how to reference it in the blueprint.
I'm finding that blueprints have pluses an minuses and would like to work through this.

Just a suggestion. What I do in my own flask app is keep main.py for running the whole app, and move any methods or initialisations to __init__.py (under blueprints). Then, if I would want to reference it from say, blueprint1.py, I would do from blueprints import ....

Structures for Flask applications that gets bigger are tricky (circular imports...).
For your problem, one way is to move the flask app creation in mainfolder/__init__.py and keep the bulk of your functions in main:
I just tested this structure (derived of what I usually do which is inspired by https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world):
run_debug_app.py <--- just to call create_app and start a debug server
mainfolder/
    __init__.py <--- new file
    main.py
    blueprints/
      __init__.py <--- empty in example below

      blueprint1/
         __init__.py <--- empty in example below
         blueprint1.py

with
run_debug_app.py :
from mainfolder import create_app
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = create_app()
   print("DEBUG ONLY WITH THIS SERVER")
   app.run(debug=True,host=None,port=None)

mainfolder/__init__.py:
from flask import Flask
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    from mainfolder.blueprints.blueprint1.blueprint1 import mod as blueprintModule
    app.register_blueprint(blueprintModule)

    return app

mainfolder/main.py:
def get_hello_world_text():
    return "Hello World"

mainfolder/blueprint1/blueprint1.py:
from flask import Blueprint
from mainfolder.main import get_hello_world_text

mod = Blueprint('blueprint1', __name__, url_prefix=None)

    
@mod.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello_world():
    return get_hello_world_text()

To go forward, I advise you to have a look at https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world for the structure of a large Flask app.
